# Android Material switches

Tags: android, material-design, uiswitch

I want to use exact Material switches in my app. Exactly the ones in the Google design guidelines.
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch
Can someone please help how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That component is called Switch and is available as a part of official support library from Google. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html